# Why do assets on Rails compile slower in production than on my staging server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I don't get it. Same basic Ubuntu server running on AWS EC2, with the production server having more memory and disk space. Same assets, of course.

But the staging server finishes in about 64 seconds, whereas the production server is taking about 208 seconds. I refer to the one as my staging server, but they both using product for the rails env.

Boot time for the rails app is significantly higher on production, too - over 3 1/2 minutes.

I didn't notice the discrepancy until I started using webpacker. I only have a few tiny JS files using webpacker, though. Not compiling any images or CSS with it - I'm using sprockets for that.

Any ideas why this is the case, and how I can speedup production?

Comment: Maybe the node(s) is/are bad. Can you easily replace your production ec2 instance/cluster with new nodes to see if it's an issue with the node itself (shoot the other node in the head)? Or perhaps you have a noisy neighbor and you're on one of the ec2 instances that are susceptible to that problem (mainly the t1/t2/low cost ones), so something someone else on your hardware is doing is causing latency for you.

Comment: I could replace the instance, but not easily. Will have to try that, though, if nothing else helps.

Comment: Do you using specific configuration of webpack for a staging env? Because I there are some differences in using staging or production config like "For example, the below command will compile assets in production mode but will use staging configurations from config/webpacker.yml if available or use fallback production environment configuration:

RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rails assets:precompile"    more details here https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/webpacker/3.5.5#Custom_Rails_environments  I would suggest to you to check webpack configurations if there are any differences in ENV settings.

Comment: Did you try to run staging environment on the same EC2 with production? I guess the differences between staging.rb and production.rb could be the cause.